# How to Call Partial View with Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to search on the database, and load only the View, and not refresh the entire page. A function in Js calls my method on the controller, when clicking on search, and the controller returns the View.

```
function Pesquisa()
{
  let campo = document.getElementsByName("campo");
  let pesquisa = document.getElementsByName("EdtPesquisa");
  let condicao = document.getElementsByName("pesquisa");

  let scampo = Array();
  let spesquisa = Array();
  let scondicao = Array();

  let sNomeGrid = ($(this).find("a").text());    

  for (var indice = 0; indice < pesquisa.length; indice++)
  {
    string = pesquisa[indice].value;

    if (string.trim() != "")
    {           
        scampo[indice] = campo[indice].id;
        scondicao[indice] = condicao[indice].value;
        spesquisa[indice] = pesquisa[indice].value;            
    }
  }

window.location.href = "/MenuPrincipal/RetornarView?sNomeGrid=" + "Unidade" + "&listacampo=" + scampo + "&listacondicao=" + scondicao + "&listapesquisa=" + spesquisa;
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult RetornarView(string sNomeGrid, List<string> listacampo, List<string> listacondicao, List<string> listapesquisa)
{
    var sWhere = "";

    if (listacampo.Count > 0)
    {
        Pesquisa _Pesquisa = new Pesquisa();

        sWhere = _Pesquisa.Pesquisar(listacampo, listacondicao, listapesquisa);
    }

    if (sNomeGrid == "Unidade")
    {
        var listaunidade = _UnidadeRepositorio.ListarMenu(sWhere);

        return View("Unidade", listaunidade);
    }

    return View("MenuPrincipal");
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<ApesWeb.Models.Classes.Unidade>

<div class="tabela-responsive">
<table id="tabela" class="tabela tabela-hover"
       data-toggle="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="idunidade" name="campo">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.idunidade)</th>
            <th id="sdescricao" name="campo">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sdescricao)</th>
            <th id="sunidade" name="campo">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sunidade)</th>
            <th id="sdigitavolume" name="campo">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sdigitavolume)</th>
            <th id="spadraosistema" name="campo">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.spadraosistema)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="inputWithIcon">
                    <select name="pesquisa" />
                    <input type="text" name="EdtPesquisa"/>
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" onclick="Pesquisa()"></i>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="inputWithIcon">
                    <select name="pesquisa"/>
                    <input type="text" name="EdtPesquisa"/>
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"  onclick="Pesquisa()"></i>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="inputWithIcon">
                    <select name="pesquisa" />
                    <input type="text" name="EdtPesquisa"/>
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"  onclick="Pesquisa()"></i>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="inputWithIcon">
                    <select name="pesquisa" />
                    <input type="text" name="EdtPesquisa"/>
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"  onclick="Pesquisa()"></i>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="inputWithIcon">
                    <select name="pesquisa" />
                    <input type="text" name="EdtPesquisa"/>
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"  onclick="Pesquisa()"></i>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var Unidade in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Unidade.idunidade) 
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Unidade.sdescricao)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Unidade.sunidade)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Unidade.sdigitavolume)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => Unidade.spadraosistema)
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Returns the View with the list to fill the Table, but in this process the entire page is refreshed.

Comment: I would use jQuery in your case. You could make an http request to your controller method and then you would get the html back and could insert it or replace it with the current view. All of that works without reloading the page

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following methods according to your needs:

***Method I:*** If you want to use ViewData, try this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/PathToYourView.cshtml", null, 
    new ViewDataDictionary { { "VariableName", "some value" } })
```

And to retrieve the passed in values:

```
@{
    string valuePassedIn = this.ViewData.ContainsKey("VariableName") ? 
        this.ViewData["VariableName"].ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```

***Method II:*** If you just render a partial with just the partial name:

```
@Html.Partial("_SomePartial", Model)
```

***Method II:*** Render PartialView using jQuery Ajax call:

Firstly wrap your body content in a div and assign any id to it in _Layout page:

```
<div id="div-page-content" class="page-content">
    @RenderBody() 
</div>
```

Here is the menu item used for rendering PartialView in _Layout page:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="nav-item  ">
        <a href="#" onclick="renderPartial(event, 'Account', '_Register')" class="nav-link">
            <span class="title">Create New User</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Define the javascript function for click event in _Layout page:

```
function renderPartial(e, controller, action) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var controllerName = controller;
    var actionName = action;
 
    if (String(actionName).trim() == '') {
        return false;
    }
    if (typeof (controllerName) == "undefined") {
        return false;
    }
 
    var url = "/" + controllerName + "/" + actionName;
 
    ////Open url in new tab with ctrl key press
    //if (e.ctrlKey) {
    //    window.open(url, '_blank');
    //    e.stopPropagation();
    //    return false;
    //}
 
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { /* additional parameters */ },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
 
        success: function (data) {
            var requestedUrl = String(this.url).replace(/[&?]X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest/i, "");
            if (typeof (requestedUrl) == "undefined" || requestedUrl == 'undefined') {
                requestedUrl = window.location.href;
            }
 
            // if the url is the same, replace the state
            if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
                if (window.location.href == requestedUrl) {
                    history.replaceState({ html: '' }, document.title, requestedUrl);
                }
                else {
                    history.pushState({ html: '' }, document.title, requestedUrl);
                }
            }

            $("#div-page-content").html(data); 
        },
        error: function (data) { onError(data); }
    });
};
```

Define your PartialView as shown below:

```
<div>
    ... partial view content goes here >
</div>
```

Add the Action metdod to the Controller as shown below:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public PartialViewResult _Register(/* additional parameters */)
{
    return PartialView();
}
```